# Implement responsive overflow overlay

Tags: html, css, overflow

How to make block with scrollbar appearing over it without resizing its contents. And it should be responsive. Same thing as `overflow: overlay` in Chrome.

Example:

[image: screenvideo of result]

Template: http://jsfiddle.net/3gf520ht/

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
main { width: 80%; height: 80%; margin: 10vh auto; border: 1px solid; }
article { text-align: justify; }

main {
  padding: 0 2em;
  overflow: overlay;
}

article {
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pellentesque convallis vestibulum. Proin sed porta urna, eu fermentum velit. Nulla quis accumsan augue, mollis eleifend felis. Aenean venenatis faucibus erat, non ornare ex efficitur ut. Ut ligula urna, auctor non velit quis, ultricies aliquet diam. Nulla quis scelerisque nisl, rutrum consectetur diam. Etiam bibendum tellus orci, iaculis varius risus congue vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum sed velit sit amet quam ultrices facilisis. Mauris malesuada vehicula purus, in blandit lectus pellentesque in. Duis luctus, risus et molestie venenatis, libero ligula volutpat augue, vitae bibendum arcu leo vel ligula. Etiam aliquet semper velit ut fringilla.</article>
</main>
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/923597/178988)

Comment: @VXp, in case of `overflow: auto` when scroll appears it moves right limit for text, but I want scroll to overlap padding without impact on text limits (take a look at gif).

Comment: Yes, overlooked that part. Try searching google for a pure CSS solution (you probably already have), I can take a closer look at it tomorrow, no more time today.

Comment: @VXp, I've tried but actually didn't found anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the classic solution to this is to use `overflow-y: visible;`

Comment: @philr, more details, please. I need it to scroll.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://jsfiddle.net/3gf520ht/1/

Comment: @philr, no, scrollbar should disappear if not overflown.